# Receta de Cocina

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Estoy traduciendo una parte de un pequeño script. aparece en http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/integrating-google-rich-snippets-into-a-wordpress-theme/

Aquí aparece como queda en ingles que será bastante similar a la forma en que aparecerá el resultado en español.

```
Recipe type:
 <time itemprop="recipeCategory">'
Yield:      "recipeYield">'.
Prep time:  "prepTime">
Cook time:  "cookTime">'
Total time: "totalTime">';
```

Tengo claro a que pertenecen todos los elementos, pero, en algunos casos, no tengo claro que esté poniendo los términos óptimos.
Por ejemplo:

- Recipe type me parece que sea tipo de receta (aqui se colocará si es
  postre, entrante, etc)
- Yield tengo raciones y creo que si sea el más apropiado.
- Prep time: Tiempo de preparación (sin embargo no quiero que se
  confunda con el tiempo total. esto se refiere al tiempo que se
  necesita antes de empezar a cocinar pelar papas etc)
- Cook time: tiempo de cocción ( ese es el tiempo por ejemplo que los alimentos van a estar al fuego, o en el horno)
- Total time: Tiempo total

El problema que se me hace es que tiempo de preparación pueda confundirse con tiempo total. Sin embargo por razones de contenido y por la forma en que supongo que se busque esta información en google las palabras `tiempo de preparación` quiero incluirla. ¿Será mejor donde prep time poner preparativos y donde dice total time poner tiempo total de preparación?

Quiero algunas ideas, por favor.

Comment: Una puntuación y ortografía más cuidadas ayudarían a comprender la pregunta. Un mejor formato de la lista enumerada, también.

Comment: Incluso sería más útil preguntar cada elemento por separado, en mi opinión, en de vez un "quiero ideas". ;)

Comment: Yo también estoy con vosotros, un enunciado con tantas preguntas es probable que no acabe de complacer al que realiza la pregunta.

Comment: Hay libertad total para editar la pregunta. Como siempre. No encontré mejor forma de plantearlo, el problema fundamental es con la confusión de tiempo de preparación y tiempo total. ¿Entonces ustedes consideran que es mejor cerrar la prergunta? Además de lo mal que puede estar formulada la pregunta se aprecian ganas de no responder. Poca voluntad. Quizá m,i forma de escribir le ha resultado molesta a alguien, yo no lo he hecho por molestar. De cualquier modo si a alguien le ha molestado algo lo mejor sería decirlo. Yo por ejemplo ahora estoy diciendo lo que me parece esta actuación coordinada.

Comment: Ya siempre que pongo una pregunta por normal que sea siempre viene uno y sin pasar un minuto me pone un menos uno. Les agradezco de cualquier modo a los que critican pero dan la cara. Gracias.

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero quizá no es nuestra intención que te sientas mal por criticarte, yo al menos ni lo he intentado, pero quizá el título de la pregunta no va con el texto, además que englobas demasiados términos en la pregunta que tu ya comprendes, y solo dos de ellos son los que dudas. Yo no soy de los que editan preguntas, es mucho más sencillo ofender a alguien por hacer eso, que intentar dar consejos de como se podría reformular, para que entrase en consonancia con lo que debería ser una pregunta para este sitio.

Comment: hay días en los que no se nos da bien escribir, y en otros sitios de StackExchange he visto cierres por menos cosa... aberrantes, lo menos que intentamos es evitar responder, de hecho estamos aquí no por la reputación, sino para resolver dudas, igual que tu también estás aquí por esa misma razón. Intenta no sentirte molesto por algunos comentarios, aunque se que es dificil (yo soy español en stackoverflow, y no muy bueno, y puedes flipar por equivocarte en una letra, las maravillas que escupe la gente). A mi no me parece que la pregunta sea mala, de hecho no puse -1...

Comment: pero creo que tendría que reformularse, para hacer la pregunta mejor entendible, o mejor buscable para el resto de usuarios. Esto es más hacer preguntas a bulto, antes de preguntar a veces tienes que pensar que vas a preguntar, porque de la comunidad depende que muchas otras personas puedan resolver sus dudas sin necesidad de formular una pregunta, con el riesgo de que este duplicada. Ya paro de escribir, pero necesitaba expresarme largo y tendido. Saludos @ErnestoMarrero

Comment: @Laura gracias por la edición

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Recipe type: En general "Tipo de receta" (como "Entradas", "Sopas", etc.). Pero también podría representar particiones como "Comida árabe", ... o "Platillos econónicos". No se me ocurre un ejemplo en el que "tipo de receta" pueda ser malentendido.
>
> Yield: En español es equivalente a "rinde". Puede ser en porciones, en litros (para jugos, por ejemplo), en kilos (para dulces)
>
> Prep time: Tiempo de preparación. No hay confusión posible.
>
> Cook time: Tiempo de cocción. No hay confusión posible.
>
> Total time: Tiempo total. No hay confusión posible.

Comment: en general acepto tu respuesta no obstante rinde no lo utilizaré porque yo entiendo que las personas difícilmente busquen rinde relacionado con una receta me decanto más por raciones (parecido me sucede con comensales que me parece la más apropiada)

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero Ejemplos de utilización de "rinde". Busca la palabra "rinde" en los siguientes enlaces: http://allrecipes.com.mx/receta/304/carnitas-en-manteca.aspx http://allrecipes.com.mx/receta/4082/conserva-de-chiles-jalape-os-en-vinagre.aspx http://www.taringa.net/posts/recetas-y-cocina/2865759/Recetas-de-panaderia-y-reposteria-_parte-1_.html http://www.petitchef.es/recetas/pan-de-pascua-chileno-fid-1204591 http://cocina.itematika.com/receta/c2597/mermelada-de-zapallo-calabaza.html

Comment: Pero nadie buisca cuanto rinde un plato o una receta, esa es la razón. La gente busca para cuantos comensales puede elaborarse una ración o para cuantos personas, o cuantas raciones. rinde queda muy feo, horrible para una receta de cocina en español. En esos sitios no viene rinde como titular de un subepigrafe de la receta que es de lo que se trata. Y aunque estuviera en algún sitio la palabra rinde no me interesa para esto..